# db model - fields or dictionary of fields

Tags: python, django, database

I'm working on some project in django. In Models I have class `Object` and I want to add settings to the `Object` (`Object` are stored in database).

I consider two options:

1. Add every settings attributes to class `Object` as class members
2. Add dictionary with settings attributes to class `Object` as one class member

How you think which option is better? or maybe you have another one.

Comment: why do you want this? you dont need to save settings into db and better rename your model. ``Object`` may already be in use by django/python

Comment: Because each `Object` will have another settings (it isn't settings.py from dajngo framework). In python is already used `object` with lowercase `o`.

Answer (score 0):

you can add to your model obj a new class, and add there any thing that you like. (look at django class Meta)

```
class YourModel(Model):

    field_one = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, default="")  
    field_two = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, default="")  


    class YourMeta:
        settings_field_one = 'any value..'
        settings_field_two = 'any value..'
```

and then you can access it like:

```
YourModel.YourMeta.settings_field_one
```

Comment: How can I do it? I didn't find something interesting about django class Meta .

Comment: Your example doesn't work. Where will `settings_field_one` be stored?

Comment: Also doesn't work. But I want store data in database because each object will have different settings.

Comment: so in this case save it as row data. on models.TextField. (json formated to string).